# JS code for text dependent on dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some JavaScript into my HTML for the first time.

Have made it this far from helpful replies on this forum; I have something that I think is close, but doesn't work:

**HTML**

```
<select id="carSelect">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>

<p id="choiceDisplay">
  Selection Display
</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('select').change(function(){
        const options = $("option");
    let selectedOption = "";
    let displayString = "";
    options.each(function(index){
        let option = options[index];
      if($(option).prop("selected")) {
        selectedOption = $(option).val();
      };
      if(selecetedOption === "Audi") {
        displayString = "Oh I used to have one of those";
      };
    });
    $("#choiceDisplay").empty().append(displayString);
});
```

I have a [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mL2c2xb6/1/) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you just have a typo:

```
if (selecetedOption === "Audi") {
```

Anyway, you probably don't need that `.each` block to get the value from the `<select>`:

```js
$("select").change((e) => {
  const value = e.target.value || '☝️ Please, select an option';
  const displayString = value === "Audi" ? "Audi - Oh I used to have one of those" : value;

  $("#choiceDisplay").empty().append(displayString);
});
```

```html
<select id="carSelect">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>

<p id="choiceDisplay">☝️ Please, select an option.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this simple solution? Hope it helps!

```js
$("select").change(function(){
  let displayString = "";
  let selectedOption = $('select[id="carSelect"]');
  displayString = (selectedOption.val() === "Audi") ? selectedOption.val() + " Oh I used to have one of those" : selectedOption.val();
  $("#choiceDisplay").empty().append(displayString);
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="carSelect">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>
<p id="choiceDisplay">
  Selection Display
</p>
```